# Выполнить скрипт при загрузке страницы

Tags: javascript

Не силён в js, нужно при загрузке выполнить этот скрипт:

```
$('#myTab a[href="#profile"]').tab('show')
```

Напишите полный пример, пожалуйста, а не только `<body onLoad="load()">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 // executes when HTML-Document is loaded and DOM is ready
 alert("document is ready");
 $('#myTab a[href="#profile"]').tab('show');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите выполнить скрипт при загрузке страницы, то, исходя из того, что jQuery у вас уже есть, делаете так:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#myTab a[href="#profile"]').tab('show')
});
```

Если вы хотите выполнить скрипт после загрузки страницы, то делаете так:

```
$(window).load(function() {
   $('#myTab a[href="#profile"]').tab('show')
});
```